# Get bank name from routing number

Tags: php, javascript, stripe-payments, banking, sensitive-data

Googling for an array of common [routing numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_transit_number) and their US-based bank names pulls up a whole list of spammy sites. Can anyone point me to where I could find such an array or better yet a javascript/jquery plugin that handles the routing number parsing?

I know [Stripe](https://stripe.com) must at least have this list because they tell me my bank name when I give them my routing number during their OAuth protocol.

If it is not possible for me to get this list, I guess Stripe must have special clearance(?) which seems strange to me since these numbers are the same for everyone who uses each bank.

Regardless, what's the deal with the scarcity of information here?

Comment: You might be looking for something like this (not free): http://www.lyonslive.com/Routing-Number-Verification/Routing-Number-Database.aspx. Update: one site that had some legal trouble when they republished the information listed their source as: https://www.fededirectory.frb.org/download.cfm - hope this is of some use!

Comment: I assume you mean US banks, so have have made a small clarification. I'm in the UK and have never heard of 'routing numbers' - I think it's the equivalent of our _sort code_.

Comment: @animuson This question was unfairly closed. The question and answer both are facts. There are no opinions expressed nor would they be invited by the question.

Comment: why was this closed it is a very legit question.

Comment: @MorrisS Asking for tools, libraries or off-site resources is considered off-topic on Stack Overflow. When you take a look at the answer to this question, you can see why: It's very hard to keep answers up-to-date.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The list is available here: <s>https://www.fededirectory.frb.org/FedACHdir.txt</s> ([replacement link](https://github.com/gatepay/FedACHdir/raw/master/FedACHdir.txt))

Even better, [routingnumbers.info](https://www.routingnumbers.info) has an API that allows to access it like this:

```
https://www.routingnumbers.info/api/data.json?rn=xxxxxxxxxx
```

It returns a JSON object where `customer_name` is the name of the bank.

Comment: Useful answer here - http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4040/1511

Comment: That site looks like it might or might not be legit. Couldn't figure out who runs it, and rate limits, etc.

Comment: www.routingnumbers.info looks great but they now display a message warning their data may be out of date.